# Kotlin, representing an undefined yet value

Tags: java, kotlin, undefined

So the big thing about `Kotlin` that it forces you to *not* implement the `null` idea in your project.

what is the replacement of the `null` idea then, if for example you have to create a new object `Foo()` then fill in it's properties *(like filling a form for example)*
`foo.name = "foo"`, `foo.age = 10`, *etc...*

 then check which fields have not been assigned with a value and warn the user to fill it in.

i can simply use the `?` on the variables types and check if it's null but that's against the whole idea of **getting rid of `Null Pointer Exception`**

is there any good implementation of an ***undefined yet field*** in Kotlin .

Comment: could the down-voter explain his view point i'll be happy to hear it

Comment: Have an upvote. It seems that there are some people on SO who systematically downvote Kotlin questions

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> So the big thing about Kotlin that it forces you to not implement the null idea in your project.

No. The "Null Safety" concept in Kotlin does not mean do eliminate all null values. Actually, even exactly the contrary: you can now safely use null values. The idea is to prevent calls on null references at *runtime*. To achieve this, Kotlin forces you to deal with potential null values at *compile time*.

> i can simply use the ? on the variables types and check if it's null
>   but that's against the whole idea of getting rid of Null Pointer
>   Exception

The architects of Kotlin have put a lot of effort into the concept of "?". The nullable type is intended to define an undefined state. And because it is now safe to use null values, there are concepts like [Safe Calls](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#safe-calls).), [Elvis Operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#elvis-operator) or [Safe Casts](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#safe-casts) to handle null values efficiently (and not just put `if (a != null)` around it).

Comment: So it's not `'Don't use null'` its `'it's safe now to use null'`

Comment: Even though it's safe to use nulls, your code will probably look better if you avoid using it when you can. For example when the property has a good default value.

Answer (score 2):

The idiomatic way to deal with the absence of a value is to use null and null-safe operations.  That said, you *could* use java 8's `Optional`, but there is no reason to because the language provides equivalent functionality.  For example, you could do

```
val anOptional: Optional<Foo> = 
   Optional.ofNullable(expr)                 // start with a nullable value
      .map { o -> someExpression }           // map
      .filter { o -> aBooleanExpression }    // filter
      .orElse(aDefaultValue)                 // default if empty
```

But kotlin offers the same functionality using null-safe operations:

```
val aNullable: Foo? = 
   expr                                      // start with a nullable value
      ?.let { o -> someExpression }          // map
      ?.takeIf { aBooleanExpression }        // filter
      ?: aDefaultValue                       // default if null
```